# (SQL) Select query involving join that adds a level of detail

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm familiar with the basic joins, but I've only ever used them to tack on columns as opposed to adding a level of detail.

Let's say I have tables **TableA** and **TableB** (see image below). With the following:

'*Key*' represents a person

'*Age*' the person's age

'*Earned*' amount of money they made

'*Bucket*' type of bucket sold

So in **TableA**, it shows how much money a person made at certain ages. **TableB** shows the % split of the money they earned from selling different types of buckets--for each person, '*Split*' adds up to 100 across all buckets.

Given those two tables, how do I query how much each person made at the different ages and bucket combinations?

[image]

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Never mind, I figured it out. For those curious:

```
SELECT 
    a.Masterkey, 
    a.Age, 
    b.Bucket, 
    a.Earned * b.Split/100 AS Earned
FROM 
    TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b
ON
    a.Masterkey = b.Masterkey
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

Comment: Certainly sounds like a homework problem.  What have you tried?

Comment: It's not; it's a work-related on much bigger tables and more columns. I simplified it because once I see an example, I can adapt it to my situation.

Comment: @HarryLime post the sample data in text instead of image also add what ever you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You can do math in your `SELECT` clause.  Just join the tables like you normally would, and `SELECT EARNED * SPLIT / 100` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

This should get what you need:

```
declare @e table (pk nvarchar(2),Age int,Earned decimal(10,2));
declare @s table (pk nvarchar(2),Bucket nvarchar(1),Split decimal(10,2));

insert into @e values ('a1',6,10),('a1',7,20),('b1',14,50),('b1',15,100);
insert into @s values ('a1','A',25),('a1','B',75),('b1','A',50),('b1','B',50);

select e.pk
        ,e.Age
        ,s.Bucket
        ,e.Earned * (s.Split/100) as Earned
from @e e
    left join @s s
        on e.pk = s.pk;
```

Output:

```
+----+-----+--------+-------------+
| pk | Age | Bucket |   Earned    |
+----+-----+--------+-------------+
| a1 |   6 | A      |  2.50000000 |
| a1 |   6 | B      |  7.50000000 |
| a1 |   7 | A      |  5.00000000 |
| a1 |   7 | B      | 15.00000000 |
| b1 |  14 | A      | 25.00000000 |
| b1 |  14 | B      | 25.00000000 |
| b1 |  15 | A      | 50.00000000 |
| b1 |  15 | B      | 50.00000000 |
+----+-----+--------+-------------+
```